# pivot table appearance

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

Can we create category for Pivot table field list which appears in right side pane after opening a pivot table.For example normally there will be some check boxes to be selected.I want certain check boxes to come under a group or folder. I see the same functionality is supported in cubes excel reporting.Is it the way you write the queries to pull and do group by
Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with not possible, but someone may have a fancy trick I'm not aware of. Pivot tables are fundamentally 2-dimensional, where OLAP allows multi-dimensional data. There are a number of tricks you can try with grouping data, however, that might get you part of the way to where you want to go. [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/group-items-in-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-field-HP005200511.aspx)'s a start.